# Is this really an Atari 2600?

Tags: atari-2600

I saw this labeled as an Atari 2600. However I thought all 2600s had toggle switches. This has flat switches. Its also all black, while all the ones I've seen have fake wood trim. Is it real?

[image]

Comment: As well as the Jnr pictured, which toumas has already answered on, there are a bunch of other types: there's the original woodgrain in both six-switch and four-switch forms (both VCSs), there's an all-black version of that known as the Darth Vader (which is the first thing labelled 2600), and there's a Japanese model that's similar in size to the Jnr but flat and rounded (the Atari 2800), and that shape was sold in the US as one of the licensed Sears-branded Ataris. The Jnr also comes with a few different versions of the faceplate, including an all-black version.

Comment: I didnt realize there were so many versions.  Not that I looked into it, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does look like [Atari 2600 Jr](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_2600#Atari_2600_Jr.) model, which is smaller, cost reduced version from 1986.

[image]

Comment: Thats it.  I was thinking of getting it...  But I just checked eBay and it would appear the seller is pricing it way too high.

Comment: @Keltari: If you can get a picture of the bottom, there are two different types of Atari 2600jr consoles, one of which is very common (and which I accidentally fried), and one of which is very rare.  Ben Heckendorn did a YouTube video just a few days ago about the latter.

Comment: @supercat What would you be looking for to see if it is this Janus model?  I googled, but the only thing I can find is Ben's video and someone on the Atari forum also asking how to identify one.  Also, even if it is rare, does it make it more valuable.  Since I can find no reference of it, I cant see a price.

Comment: @Keltari: All I know about the units is what's in Ben's video.  I'm not sure exactly what the market would be, but they are sufficiently rare that Atari researchers might be willing to pay hundreds of dollars.  I think it's really doubtful that what you're looking at is one of those, but I just saw Ben's video and thought you might find it interesting.

Comment: I've had a couple of those.  Not the most durable of the 2600 lineup.  Although, at this point every 2600 I've ever had has now blown up (even my early serial number heavy sixer) :-( and all I have left is a modded 7800...